What if the dot product of gradient vector of two curves is zero at a point (x,y)?
If say the grad(f)•grad(g) at point (x,y) on both the curves is zero. Is it sufficient to show that the curves intersect orthogonally?

Yes it is. What is your doubt?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, the question was that given an analytic function show that the component functions u(x,y) and v(x,y) intersect perpendicularly. So I showed that the dot product of the gradient of the level curve of the functions is zero, but was just uncertain if that was sufficient. Thanks for the help.

Both the curves? What curves? You mean level curves $f=c_1$ and $g=c_2$? What you just said in your last comment likewise doesn't make sense. Functions do not intersect. Ordinarily, people identify functions with their graphs, but here you specifically are referring to level sets.

Sorry I meant the level curves of u = c1 and v = c2 in the last comment instead of functions.

So, yes, two lines in the plane are orthogonal if and only if their normal vectors are orthogonal .
